# Parse login screen using Back4app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am building an app that uses parse to login using the back4app system.

Checked all the code and their are no errors, however when I run the app on the emulator it does start and the following has popped up in the log cat files, can somebody help me understand what is wrong.

```
04-04 13:32:38.355 3170-3170/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics, PID: 3170
                                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/Task;
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:422) at com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.Task" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-1/base.apk", zip 
file "/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-                                                                                                          
1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-    
1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file " 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics-
1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, 
/system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:422) 
at com.airrocketapps.airrocketapps.fishermanspics.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bolts.Task
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 16 more                                                                                                  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class 
loader; no stack available
```

Comment: this is the code at line 28

Comment: line 128 Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("2zj9Krftv0kSSZ54EQTevVFgmPtMzwh4iH6GTwXK")
                .clientKey("kNcw2fch9oaTY85TSgpmnwDiapQpkz3xAsFP76rg")
                .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/").build()
        );

Comment: You shouldn't publicly provide your secret  keys

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing Bolts reference in your project. Install Bolts and try again:
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android